# Dynamically add property to object in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of object and iterating that list using ng-repeat to generate table row. each `td` contains source name and checkbox. I want to bind the checkbox with a property which is not available into list. how that is possible? The list is like that:-

```
scope.reasons = [
        {sourceName:'Lack of rainfall'},
        { sourceName: 'Change in land use' },
        {sourceName:'Change in Land Cover'}
        ];
```

and the HTML code is like that:-

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="source in reasons">
    <td>{{source.sourceName}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="source.postAdequate"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if the property is not available in object, you want that object property to be added dynamically?

Comment: can you hard code some example like how the property should be?

Comment: @Mayank Nimje yes.

Comment: after checked and unchecked the check boxes the list should look like this- scope.reasons = [
        {sourceName:'Lack of rainfall',postAdequate:true },
        { sourceName: 'Change in land use',postAdequate:false },
        {sourceName:'Change in Land Cover',postAdequate:true}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `ng-model` attribute, `ng-change` is just for the checking purposes that is change detection.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="source in reasons">
      <td>{{source.sourceName}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="source.postAdequate" ng-change="changeDet()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/fy5ow4ea/)

Hope this helps

Comment: `ng-change` isn't doing anything related to question. Explanation doesn't make sense

Comment: if i use ng-model instead of ng-checked that solved. jajhakallah junaid vi. no need to use ng-change

Comment: Yes @Alamgir , its just for checking purpose you can remove it, and no problem, here to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="source.postAdequate">
```

See here `jsfiddle` link:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/5cpm48tc/2/
```

> But it will add `source.postAdequate: true/false` only if you click, remains objects will remains same.

So if you want to add `source.postAdequate: true/false` in all add in `$scope.reasons` before only.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: can't use `ng-checked` and `ng-model` on same element per docs

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, I forgot to remove, I updated answer, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-model` instead of `ng-checked` will add property internally when checkbox is changed

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="source.postAdequate"></td>
```

If you must have that property on all objects iterate the array and add it

```
scope.reasons.forEach(function(item){
   item.postAdequate = false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you loop the scope object once to initially set postAdequate:false for all items. Then bind that object in checkbox ng-model.

```
        angular.forEach($scope.reasons, function(e,i){
          e.postAdequate = false;
        });
```

html code

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="source in reasons">
<td>{{source.sourceName}}</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="source.postAdequate" ng-click="clickfunction(source.postAdequate)">
</td></tr>
</table>
```